# Can we use sirikit for record audio?

Tags: ios, audio, audio-recording, ios10, sirikit

I want to implement audio recording functionality in one of my application. is it possible using **sirikit** ? I don't find any tutorial for recording through **sirikit** right now.

Is someone can provide good tutorial on **sirikit**?

Comment: Looking for same functionality.

Comment: in Lecture 14-16 There are some audio recording session. https://www.udemy.com/ios-10-swift-3-hands-on-features-siri-kit-messages/  But it is paid :(

Comment: @ketan P, it is not about audio recording using SiriKit.

Answer (score 1):

Right know you cannot do this in way: "Hey Siri, start voice recording" or similar way.

[SiriKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH11-SW1) says:

> SiriKit support is divided into domains, each of which defines one or
>   more tasks that can be performed. In order to support SiriKit, apps
>   must support one of the following domains:
>
> - VoIP calling
> - Messaging Payments
> - Photo
> - Workouts
> - Ride booking
> - CarPlay (automotive vendors only)
> - Restaurant reservations (requires additional support from Apple)

**NOTE** that you cannot create a Siri extension for a macOS projects right know (for the time of writing this answer), despite that INIntent supports macOS.

> Is someone can provide good tutorial on sirikit?

IMHO, the best tutorial on SiriKit right know is an official documentation and projects:

- [SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/)
- [SiriKit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/index.html)
- [Intents Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents)
- [IntentsUI Framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/intentsui)
- [IntentHandling: Using the Intents framework to handle custom Siri request](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/IntentHandling/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [UnicornChat: Extending Your Apps with SiriKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UnicornChat/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't record audio using sirkit. However, you can add a button in your application by pressing which you can start recording the audio, there is limit of max 1 minute per instance